# BeforeRouteEnter not loading data to variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have set up a web API that is sending data correctly, however, my vuejs app has a data table component which I do an API call with Axios using the `BeforeRouteEnter` hook but the data from the response does not save to my data variable.

Is it such that the Data variables such as my array called `queryResult` isn't loaded until after my get request hence the reason it cannot save to it? I also tried to call the Axios code and variable update as a method and that did not work as it did not recognize the method queryDB for some reason so again it leads me to believe my timing is off.

My code is as follows:

```html
<template id="dashboard">
    <div>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <v-text-field v-model="search"
                              append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                              label="Search"
                              single-line
                              hide-details></v-text-field>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-data-table :headers="headers"
                          :items="queryResult"
                          :search="search"></v-data-table>
        </v-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
    const dashboard = Vue.component('dashboard',
        {
        template: '#dashboard',
            data() {
                return {
                    userID: 'SB',
                    password: 'Yellow',
                    search: '',
                    headers: [
                        { text: 'ID', align: 'start', filterable: true, value: 'ID'},
                        { text: 'USERNAME', value: 'USERNAME' },
                        { text: 'FIRST_NAME', value: 'FIRST_NAME' },
                        { text: 'LAST_NAME', value: 'LAST_NAME' },
                    ],
                    queryResult: [],
                }
            },
            beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
                axios.get(window.location.origin + '/home/DapperDatatableLoad', {
                    params: {}
                })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        queryResult = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                next()
            },
            methods: {
                queryDB: function () {
                    axios.get(window.location.origin + '/home/DapperDatatableLoad', {
                        params: {
                            
                        }
                    })
                        .then(function (response) {
                            queryResult = response.data;
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you want to wait until the data is loaded then move `next()` into then (and catch)

Comment: @Suit Boy Apps I have moved the next inside and you are right it delays the load until the data is loaded. However, the datatable still says no data available. I can see a json array in the response.data but it is not passing to the queryResult variable in my data section I think. Any idea if that is a timing issue?

Comment: The other issue that I see is that queryResultis part of your data object. So queryResult should be called `this.queryResult` inside of your function.

Comment: You should also check the console for errors, and install vue dev tools into your browser. This way you can actually visualize the data in your components and then debug from there. For example: https://imgur.com/a/n8uwU2k

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are saying is that the route loads before your data is present.

This makes sense as `axios.get` is asynchronous. Meaning that while `axios.get` is requesting data from the server, the main thread is still executing code. Then when `axios.get` receives data it triggers the `.then` callback.

In your case, your next command is `next()` which tells the router to go ahead and move forward in routing. This means that while `axios.get` is retrieving data you have already called `next()`.

If you want to wait for axios to get the data first you need to move `next()` to within the callback function.

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    axios.get(window.location.origin + '/home/DapperDatatableLoad', {
        params: {}
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            next();
            this.queryResult = response.data; //Notice that `queryResult` is referred to with `this.`
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            next();
            console.log(error);
        });
},
```

Another solution is to use await syntax instead

```js
async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    try{
        let response = await axios.get(window.location.origin + '/home/DapperDatatableLoad', {
            params: {}
        });
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    this.queryResult = response.data;       

    next();
},
```

Comment: This does the trick in delaying the load but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it still says no data available. I added my component tags above for the vuetify datatable. Do you see any obvious issues? It is as if queryResults is still equal to [] despite the data is loaded.

Comment: What is your output of the console. Or can you create a codepen?

Comment: Sorry for delay! The console actually shows $attr is read only error and $listener is read only error. I decided to try and put a alert(JSON.stringify(queryResult)); before the axios call and also right after next to see if queryResult the variable in data exists at this point and it says its undefined. So I am thinking that could be why data is never assigned. Do I need to do the vm => {} inside next to access the instance variable?

Comment: I fixed the $attr and $listener errors as that was due to a second vue cdn link somehow but the queryResult variable still doesnt exist when i try to assign the data to it in beforerouteenter.

Comment: Please create a codesandbox or a codepen so I can look into this more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to `data` reactive variables inside `beforeRouteEnter` but you can change the them inside `next` function.
So Your code:

```js
const dashboard = Vue.component('dashboard',
        {
        template: '#dashboard',
            data() {
                return {
                    userID: 'SB',
                    password: 'Yellow',
                    search: '',
                    headers: [
                        { text: 'ID', align: 'start', filterable: true, value: 'ID'},
                        { text: 'USERNAME', value: 'USERNAME' },
                        { text: 'FIRST_NAME', value: 'FIRST_NAME' },
                        { text: 'LAST_NAME', value: 'LAST_NAME' },
                    ],
                    queryResult: [],
                }
            },
            beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
                let data = null
                axios.get(window.location.origin + '/home/DapperDatatableLoad', {
                    params: {}
                })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        data = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                next((vm)=>{
                   vm.queryResult = data
                })
            },
            methods: {
                queryDB: function () {
                    axios.get(window.location.origin + '/home/DapperDatatableLoad', {
                        params: {
                            
                        }
                    })
                        .then(function (response) {
                            queryResult = response.data;
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }
            }
        });
```